# Unable to change http writing permission on AFS'linux terminal?

Tags: php, linux, shell, openafs

on the shell for the school server, I have

```
Normal Rights:
  system:administrators rlidwka
  http rl
  yfc439 rlidw
  httpsvc.webhost03.ucs.njit.edu rl
```

how exactly do I change the permission for http because in the php file, say I have:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("test.txt","w") or die("error");
echo fwrite($file,"Hello World. Testing!");
fclose($file);
?>
```

the php doesn't **write** to test.txt once I open the php file on the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
fs setacl ~/public_html/some.dir http write
```